# Email intent createChooser not opening from within DialogFragment

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to email a file directly from a button push on a `DialogFragment` however the intent won't open and is skipped over. Any ideas?

This code is inside the `onCreateView` method of the `DialogFragment`

```
createWithEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //create file than move right into email
                fileName = editFileName.getText().toString();

                //create file
                createFile();

                //set up email
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), fileName);
                i.setType("image/png");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From:" + user.getName() + "\n" + "\n" + "Company Name:" + user.getCompany() + "\n" + "\n" + "Date of meeting to present:");
                try {
                    getActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                //dismiss
                getDialog().dismiss();
                realm.close();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), OldLocation.class));
            }
        });
```

Comment: How are you calling `getActivity()` inside an Anonymous inner classes? Can you do that?

Comment: It works inside the class, after the email intent is skipped over it moves to the next activity through the next intent where I used `getActivity()`